# how to align two text in one button

Tags: java, android, textview, alignment

i am a new android developer,i know align two text in one button using by /n,
but don't know align two text in one button one text right alignment and another one is left align please any one help me and solve my problem, since I use Arabic language (right to left)
I want to do this programmatically, not by xml design.
I need to align two texts one below another ie, english text on top and arabic in bottom
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want left-aligned and right-aligned text in the button at the same time? eg: `LTR...........RTL` ? If so, you're going to have to have a positioning element inside the button although you could add it programatically

Comment: Sorry I need to align two texts one below another ie, english text on top and arabic in bottom

Comment: I havne't touched Android in a while so I'm not going to post as an answer but I _believe_ you'll need to set the contents of the button to be a layout element (StackPanel?) with 2 text boxes. You might wrap this inside a button control of your own which would have `.LTRText` and `.RTLText` parameters. I'm sure someone else can give you a more detailed/better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code:

```
Button  availableText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.request); 
            Spannable span =Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(availableText.getText());
            span.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL),0, 7, 
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
            span.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),8, 
            span.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
            availableText.setText(span);
```

---

Assuming you have a button defined in XML or can create one in code with text **"English\nArbi".**

The output is as follows:

[image: Button layout example]

Comment: imran if you dont mine one help please about tabhost